# Does print convert the string to unicode in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
s = '\xd6\xd0\xce\xc4'
print s
```

The excerpt of code prints

```
中文
```

Which is not expected. I can see from the ordinals that `s` is not some ascii characters because the ordinal is > 128. But is this why the `print` automatically decode the string to utf8 and print it (According to the statement of encoding at the very beginning)?

**UPDATES：**

I declared to be gbk encoded, but keep the file codec as utf8. A exception is raised :

```
SyntaxError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: illegal multibyte s
equence
```

Which indicates that a codec conversion is failed. Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `print` prints exactly the byte string you give it.  What you finally see depends on how your terminal interprets the byte string.  Apparently your terminal is set to the `gb2312` codec, which gives the result you see.

Comment: That's the problem, I decoded from 'gbk'. The bytes is `gbk` codec. But the code above runs correctly and print the original characters.

Comment: A codec transform must have happened somewhere. That's why I am guessing that print did the work. See my updates.

Comment: @zoujyjs: Well, I can only repeat myself:  `print` in Python 2.x will send exactly the bytes you give it to the terminal.  Your terminal will then use some codec to interpret its input, but it's beyond Python's control what the terminal does with the bytes it gets.  If everything is set up correctly, `sys.stdout.encoding` should show you what codec your terminal uses (or pretends to use).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it to print as you declared it, try `print repr(s)`.